# Count one's in given submatrices

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, data-structures, binary-data

I have a binary matrix of size **M*N**.
I'm given **K** queries where each consists of given sub-matrix, with upper left coord (x1,y1) and lower right coord (x2,y2).
My task is to find how many one's are in each submatrix.
I should find the best solution in terms of time complexity.

How can I achieve that?

I suppose that I should somehow pre-calculate the matrix to I can then answer the queries in O(1) time. But I'm not really sure how to pre-calculate the matrix.

Comment: The solution must be in O(1) time ? I think the best case scenario here is still O(n).

Comment: If you pre-processed the matrix into a quadtree, where each tree node kept the count of 1 values within that area, that would only be O(log n * log m) for each query, where n*m is the size of the query area. Don't think there's an O(1) solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `C(x1, y1, x2, y2)` be the number of ones in a sub-matrix with upper left coord `(x1, y1)` and lower right coord `(x2, y2)` (i.e. `x2 >= x1` and `y2 >= y1`), and let `(1, 1)` be the upper-left corner of the `MxN` binary matrix. Then:

- If `x1 > 1` and `y1 > 1`: `C(x1, y1, x2, y2) = C(1, 1, x2, y2) - C(1, 1, x2, y1-1) - C(1, 1, x1-1, y2) + C(1, 1, x1-1, y1-1)`
- If `x1 = 1` and `y1 > 1`: `C(x1, y1, x2, y2) = C(1, 1, x2, y2) - C(1, 1, x2, y1-1)`
- If `x1 > 1` and `y1 = 1`: `C(x1, y1, x2, y2) = C(1, 1, x2, y2) - C(1, 1, x1-1, y2)`
- If `x1 = 1` and `y1 = 1`: `C(x1, y1, x2, y2) = C(1, 1, x2, y2)`

If you precompute `C(1, 1, x, y)` for `1 <= x <= M` and `1 <= y <= M` in a `O(MN)` precomputation step, each query `C(x1, y1, x2, y2)` can be answered in `O(1)` time.

Comment: Thati is so called 2D prefix-sum.